# How to set blob conf in pyspark environment session

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a `pyspark` script in which I initiate a `spark` session, but I am not able to read from blob store using the `spark.read.format('json').load("my_blob_path")`. Below is my session initialisation. Please help me set my blob credentials in the environment.

```
conf = SparkConf().setAppName("session1")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("session1").getOrCreate()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set credentials of your azure-blob storage account using the `spark.conf.set` after you have initialised your spark session.

Below is the code:

```
conf = SparkConf().setAppName("session1")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("session1").getOrCreate()

spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.key.{blob_account_name}.blob.core.windows.net","{blob_account_key}")
```

This will set the account in your path and then you can read from blob using the `spark.read.format('json').load('wasb://{blob_container}@{blob_account_name}.blob.core.windows.net/{blob_path}')`

Comment: This is working for me, but I wonder is there a way to add `conf` while initialising the session?